# How do I make a newsletter of my watched tags?

Tags: support, tags, newsletter

On a specific Stack Exchange site, let's say *[History](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour)*, I have listed my watched tags. I would like to subscribe to them thanks to the newsletter [as it used to be the case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336515/4764604) before:

[image]

But it seems it isn't anymore:

[image]

Therefore, how do make a newsletter of my watched tags?

Comment: The [tag watching & ignoring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/current) on the profile setting hinted a newsletter, though I don't know if it's working or not... (or probably I'm currently watching obsolete tags...)

Answer (score 5):

It's not exactly a *newsletter*, but you can create **a digest of your favorite tags** from https://stackexchange.com/filters/:

[image]

---

It's a little annoying and confusing how this feature is separate from *watching* a tag, but that's what's available at the moment.